# Searching the rest of the folder using the last few letters of a filename that is in a for loop VBS

Tags: vbscript

Hello all~ I am new to VBS and I'm trying to find the code to search for the rest of the files in the folder that countains a specific number in the file that is in the for loop. Let me try to visualize it for you.

Current code that prints out the documents that I have to manually print out everyday:

```
'' To set the path to the current folder

set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")


currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 


set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )



'' To set the items in the current folder as "files"


set files = shFolder.Items()


'Open excel sheet to print the paper for shipping side to sign'

set objsheet = getobject(,"Excel.Application").activeworkbook.activesheet


''Start of code''

count = 1

for each files in files 
    ' If name contains "DN" '
    if inStr(files, "DN") then
        ' Print 1 time if SO'
        if inStr(files, "SO") then
            'print 1 time'
            files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
            ' Pop up to show what has been printed '
            CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Printed "+ files , 3, "\(o.o)/    The Magic Script    \(o.o)/"
            objsheet.cells(count,1) = files
            count = count + 1
            'Pause in the script'
            WScript.Sleep 5000
        end if
        if inStr(files, "SM") then
            'print 4 time using loop function and "i" as a counter'
            'Do
            '   i = i + 1
            '   files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
            'Loop until i>= 4
            'i = 0
            files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
            files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
            files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
            files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
            'Pop up to show what has been printed'
            CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Printed "+ files , 3, "\(o.o)/    The Magic Script    \(o.o)/"
            objsheet.cells(count,1) = files
            count = count + 1
            ' Pause in the script '
            WScript.Sleep 15000 
        end if
    end if
    ' if name contains "INV" '  
    if inStr(files, "INV") then
        ' Print 6 times using loop function and "j" as a counter '
        'Do
        '   j = j + 1
        '   files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        'Loop until j >= 6
        'j = 0
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        ' Pop up to show what has been printed '
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Printed "+ files , 3, "\(o.o)/    The Magic Script    \(o.o)/"
        WScript.Sleep 18000 ' Prevent Lag '
    end if
    ' if name contains "PO" '
    if inStr(files, "PO") then
        'print out 2 times'
        'Do
        '   k = k + 1
        '   files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        'Loop until k >= 2
        'k = 0
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        ' Pop up to show what has been printed '
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Printed "+ files , 3, "\(o.o)/    The Magic Script    \(o.o)/"
        WScript.Sleep 6000 'Prevent Lag'
    end if
    ' if name contains "OF" '
    if inStr(files, "OF") then
        ' print out 1 time '
        files.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
        objsheet.cells(count, 1) = files
        CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Popup "Printed "+ files , 3, "\(o.o)/    The Magic Script    \(o.o)/"
        count = count + 1
        Wscript.Sleep 5000
    end if

next

objsheet.printout

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Successfully Printed " , 10, "\(o.o)/    The Magic Script    \(o.o)/"
```

Now im trying to improve the code by matching the file containing "DN" to its corresponding file that contains "PO" or "INV" so when it prints out, it would be in order ( thus easier to staple it together ) and would save up a lot of time for people at my workplace.

An example of the saved files in a folder would be:

DN_789456 SO 13371337

DN_963258 SO 12341234

INV_785412 SO 13371337

PO_632541 SO 12341234

as you can tell, the only way to match them would be using the last 8 numbers in the file name. However, I could not find a guide/tutorial that I could follow to extract these 8 numbers and continue searching for the corresponding file in the folder.

It would be great if anyone could guide me along. Thank you in advance

Comment: `for each files in files` doesn't seem right

Comment: @GeertBellekens Can I ask whats the better way of phrasing the code in your opinion? Thank you :)

Comment: Use another variable. `files` is your collection, but you are using it as the variable for your iteration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the last occurrence of a substring you can use

```
InStrRev(string1,string2[,start[,compare]])
```

This will do what `InStr()` does but starting from the end of the string.

You can then find all files containing 'DN' and upon every match search the items again to obtain the matching 'INV' and/or 'PO' files.

Comment: Hi, Can I just clarify whats the variables in the code that you have provided. Sorry I'm just really new to this language.

Comment: VBA reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instrrev-function Note that in VBScript you cannot use named constants, just use their value.